# How do I get user and group information in Perl on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, etcpasswd, getpwuid

Perl has several built-in functions for accessing /etc/passwd on Unix systems (and elsewhere when supported) for user and group information. For instance,

```
my $name = getpwuid($uid);
```

will return the user name given the user ID, or undef if there is no such user.

If a Perl script needs to be portable and run on Unices and Windows, how should one access user and group information? ActivePerl seems to support User::grent and User::pwent modules, which provide by-field access to /etc/passwd -- even in Windows. Curiously they do not support the built-in functions getpw* and getgr*. What other alternatives are there?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`Win32::NetAdmin` module](http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/CodeDoc/libwin32/NetAdmin/NetAdmin.html).

`UserGetAttributes` and `GroupIsMember` look like they do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, Interix's build of Perl that ships with Microsoft's Services for Unix does support getpw* and friends.